# Admin login returns 'Sorry, unrecognized username or password.'

Tags: 7, users, database

When I attempt to login to my admin account, I'm getting a 'Sorry, unrecognized username or password.' message. The weird thing is that the password and username are correct. I've looked them up in the SQL database. I've even tried changing the password in the database, but have had no luck getting it to work. After every 5 attempts, I've had to use the `DELETE FROM 'flood';` sql command in order to reset the attempts.

In my local environment, I'm having no trouble logging in. This is also the first time I've attempted to login to the production website.

Is there anything I can try to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

If you changed the password in the database, it won't work - the password in the database is hashed, so entering an un-hashed password means it will never work.

Use the password recovery tool to get a new password, or use Drush:

```
drush uli
```

Either of these will help you get your password.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the server through SSH there are 2 ways to get in:

**With Drush**: execute the following command from the root of your Drupal installation, or from the website folder in a multisite installation:

```
drush uli
```

**Without Drush**: execute the following command from the root of your Drupal installation:

```
./scripts/password-hash.sh my_new_password
```

Where `my_new_password` must be replaced with the password you want for your user. This will give you the following response:

```
password: my_new_password hash: $S$DYx387nLkjxnMiupTv8ubxxnixbF3d0QchC2zhw7Y5XvlO6KqZ0T
```

This means that `$S$DYx387nLkjxnMiupTv8ubxxnixbF3d0QchC2zhw7Y5XvlO6KqZ0T` is a hashed version of the string `my_new_password` and it is the value you must add to your user in the database.

I'm not totally sure if a text hashed in this way but in a different Drupal installation (your localhost) would work... just check it.

Now, if you don't have SSH access, you can always use the `www.example.com/user/password` form to recover the password for your account. It will work if your server can send emails and you have access to the email account associated with the user you want to recover.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice. I'm working on getting Drush installed on the server. Well... I have it installed, but I need to point it to the php directory on the server, which I've not found. Anyway, when I tried the "without drush" method, I got a permission denied error. Any ideas?

Lastly, requesting a new password from user/password acts like it works, but it does not send an email. It seems everything is giving me trouble.